# Moving MySQL InnoDB database to separate drive

Tags: mysql, innodb, symlink

In my MySQL installation I have one InnoDB database that I know will grow very large so I have decided to move it to its own disk. I was hoping to do this by moving the files to the other disk and then create a symlink but I run into errors!

This is what I have done:

1) In my.cnf I have set

[mysqld]
 innodb_file_per_table

(This works, I have one .ibd per .frm in the database folder.)

2)I have checked if symlinks are ok with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "have_symlink";`

(I know that the documentation says:

> Symlinks are fully supported only for
>   MyISAM tables. For files used by
>   tables for other storage engines, you
>   may get strange problems if you try to
>   use symbolic links.

But I need foreign keys...)

3) I moved the database folder and created a symlink.

4) Restarted mysql and tried:

```
 mysql> USE db_name
 Database changed
 mysql> SHOW TABLES;
 ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './db_name/' (errno: 13)
 mysql> exit
 user@comp# perror 13
 OS error code  13:  Permission denied
```

symlink is (as expected) `lrwxrwxrwx mysql mysql db_name -> /path-to/db_name/`

database folder permissions are `drwx------ mysql mysql`

all file permissions are `-rw-rw---- mysql mysql`

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 Server with MySQL 5.1.41 (default from apt).

Have any of you done this successfully?

Comment: Easiest way is to take mysqldump and then drop schema change config and import it, if your DB is not really big.

Comment: I want to keep the rest of the databases on the system disk (for drupal and such things) and only move this specific one out of the data directory. Sorry if this wasn't clear from the question.

Comment: This might be more suited to http://serverfault.com/ - voting to migrate it...

Comment: @Norling Jr. : why dun u create another database, and mount that database directory to your desired disk ?

Comment: @ajreal: How do you mean? Using a separate MySQL instance with its data-dir set to the new disk? Wouldn't be very neat... Using a single MySQL instance all databases that are created are created relative to the data directory. I'm trying to move one of them out of there...

Comment: @Norling Jr - u dun have to create seperate instance, assume this is your database path`/database`, your existing database `/database/existing_database`, and your new database `/database/new_database`, just mount `/database/new_database` to your new disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your solution is the best idea.  See my post here:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/12/25/spreading-ibd-files-across-multiple-disks-the-optimization-that-isnt/

There is also this other thread here:

[Innodb; multiple data directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511578/innodb-multiple-data-directories)

Answer (score 17):

Turns out this works but my old enemy appArmor blocked MySQL from reading the moved directory.

```
sudo nano /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

add lines:

```
/new-db-path/ r,
/new-db-path/** rwk,
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu 12.04 after moving database and replacing it with a symbolic link. Editing the AppArmor profile as you suggest works. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Don't forget to restart the apparmor service after changing this

Comment: on Ubuntu 12.10 I have to restart both apparmor and the mysql service to have the new policy takes effect.

Answer (score 13):

Norling Jr. saved my day with the AppArmor tip, but since I had some trouble configuring it, I'm writing a more detailed answer. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Start becoming root to save the need to type all that sudos:

```
sudo su -
```

Following [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/symbolic-links.html), you first move your *already created* database dir to another path:

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/yourdatabase /new/path/
```

Here was my first trap. Check if the mysql user has access to this new path:

```
sudo -u mysql ls /new/path/yourdatabase
```

If you got access denied, you should probably give execute permission to every parent dir:

```
chmod a+x  /new  /new/path/
```

Test to access the file again. If it still doesn't work, try asking a question in Stack Overflow:-)

Link the new dir location and give it the correct permissions:

```
 ln -s /new/path/yourdatabase /var/lib/mysql/
 chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/yourdatabase
```

Let's edit AppArmor local configuration file. You shoudn't change /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld file. Edit the local conf so you won't loose it after system updates:

```
emacs /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

add Norling Jr. configurations:

```
/new/path/yourdatabase/ r,
/new/path/yourdatabase/** rwk,
```

Don't miss the last comma. Save the file and reload AppArmor configuration:

```
apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
```

This will not just reload AppArmor MySql configuration, but also test it if there isn't any syntax error (a very important thing). If you don't run the parser, the new conf won't be applied.

Finally just open mysql client and type `SHOW DATABASES`. If your database appears, everything is probably fine. Type 'USE yourdatabase' for another check.

A more robust test would also reload the mysql service: 'service mysql restart' and try to access your database.

Now I'll remember next time I need to do it. Google and SO together are the best notebook in the world :-)

Comment: this was incredibly helpful, THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to use local mounts (bindings) with appropriate permissions and mount oprions (including the selinux or apparmor contexts):

```
/dev/sdc on /var/lib/mysql/my-db/
/dev/sdd on /var/lib/mysql/her-db/
fs.example.com:/path/to/wherever on /var/lib/mysql/my-other-db/
```

Though **I haven't tested this solution** so use at your own risk.

Comment: I can confirm this works.  You have to dedicate a whole partition to just the mysql subdir, but once you do that and mount it properly it works great.